# Update property in array in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I have the following structure in RethinkDB

`{ "id": "1", "values": [{ "id": 1, "firstname": "foo" }] },
{ "id": "2", "values": [{ "id": 2, "firstname": "bar" }] }`

How can I update each "values" array and add an additional property to it?

For instance I'd like to achieve

`{ "id":  "1", "values": [{ "id": 1, "firstname": "foo", "lastname": null }] },
{ "id":  "2", "values": [{ "id": 2, "firstname": "bar", "lastname": null }] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
r.table('test').get(id).update(function(row) {
  return {values: row('values').map(function(val) 
    return val.merge({lastname: null});
  });
})
```